# Random choice one of two type sentences that contain parts of speech

Tags: python-3.x

**Task:** random choice one of two type sentences with random.randint(), then print their content with random.choice().

I wrote this code:

```
import random

i = 0
ii = 0
line1 = ''

articles = ['the', 'a', 'an']
nouns = ['cat', 'dog', 'man', 'woman']
verbs = ['sang', 'run', 'jumped']
adverb = ['loudly', 'quietly', 'well', 'badly']
structure1 = [articles, nouns, verbs, adverb]
structure2 = [articles, nouns, verbs]

while i < 5:
    if random.randint(1,2) == 1:
        c = len(structure1)
        while ii < c:
            line1 += str(random.choice(structure1[ii])) + ' '
            ii += 1
        print (line1)
    else:
        c = len(structure2)
        while ii < c:
            line1 += str(random.choice(structure2[ii])) + ' '
            ii += 1
        print (line1)

    i += 1;
```

**It is work.** There is no problem.

But I think this code is too complicated. 
Can u help me to make this code more simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map a random choice between `structure1` and `structure2` to `random.choice`:

```
for _ in range(5):
    print(' '.join(map(random.choice, random.choice((structure1, structure2)))))
```

Sample output:

```
the man run
a woman sang badly
the woman jumped loudly
the woman jumped quietly
the cat run loudly
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks like your code is a little overcomplicated. Here is how you can improve it:

```
import random


articles = ['the', 'a', 'an']
nouns = ['cat', 'dog', 'man', 'woman']
verbs = ['sang', 'run', 'jumped']
adverb = ['loudly', 'quietly', 'well', 'badly', '']
structure1 = [articles, nouns, verbs, adverb]


def generate_sentence_pythonic():
    return ' '.join([random.choice(obj) for obj in structure1])


def generate_sentence():
    res = []
    for obj in structure1:
        res.append(random.choice(obj))
    return ' '.join(res)

# Number of sentences you want to generate
n = 1

for i in range(n):
    print(generate_sentence())
    print(generate_sentence_pythonic())
```

There are two functions I included `generate_sentence_pythonic` and `generate_sentence` to generate the sentence.